# In an array, display an object only once if it has the same id, but still display other properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

What I would like to achieve is that I want to display `fromUser`s one by one, **but no duplicates**. So if I have 2 messages from the same John (same `fromUserId`), then I want this John's name to appear only once, because it's the same John with the same `fromUserId`. Then once I click on John's name, then I would see 2 messages (hi + hey). We cannot get rid of any objects because the `message` are different and I still need to display these messages. Is it possible to implement this? I am using Node.js, Mongodb, Mongoose, and React.

```
[
    {
        "message": "hi",
        "fromUser": "John",
        "fromUserId": "5edb1f10b82175355479f05a",
    },
    {
        "message": "hey",
        "fromUser": "John",
        "fromUserId": "5edb1f10b82175355479f05a",
    },
    {
        "message": "ola",
        "fromUser": "Jane",
        "fromUserId": "5ed9d49c7e516616600eb693",
    }
]
```

Render:

```
            <div>
                {this.state.from.map((from) => {
                    return <div key={from._id}>{from.fromUser}</div>;
                })}
            </div>
```

Axios get request:

```
            axios.get('/api/getMessage', { headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': token } }).then((res) => {
                this.setState({ from: res.data });
            });
```

State in class component:

```
    this.state = {
        message: '',
        from: [],
    };
```

Comment: Remove duplicates in the entire data set, or only in sequential runs? Can you clarify expected result? I.E. grouped globally `[[john, john, john], [jane, jane]]` or grouped sequentially `[[john, john], jane, john, jane]`.

Comment: [[john, john, john], [jane, jane]] is correct but [[john, message, message]], [jane, message] should be more ideal, because if the same john sent many messages then I do not need his name (the same John) more than once, but I need every single message from john etc. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uses an object map to collect messages into arrays.  Resultant data in the form of:
`[ { _id, fromUser, messages} ... ]`

```js
const fromCollectMessages = from =>
  Object.values(from.reduce((chats,{message:m, fromUserId: _id, fromUser})=>{
    chats[_id] = chats[_id] || { _id, fromUser }
    chats[_id].messages = chats[_id].messages || []
    chats[_id].messages.push(m)
    return chats
  },{}))

const data=[
    {
        "message": "hi",
        "fromUser": "John",
        "fromUserId": "5edb1f10b82175355479f05a",
    },
    {
        "message": "hey",
        "fromUser": "John",
        "fromUserId": "5edb1f10b82175355479f05a",
    },
    {
        "message": "ola2",
        "fromUser": "Jane",
        "fromUserId": "5ed9d49c7e516616600eb693",
    },
    {
        "message": "hi2",
        "fromUser": "John",
        "fromUserId": "5edb1f10b82175355479f05a",
    },
    {
        "message": "ola",
        "fromUser": "Jane",
        "fromUserId": "5ed9d49c7e516616600eb693",
    }
]

console.log(fromCollectMessages(data))

const { Component } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM,
      el = document.getElementById('app')
      
class Name extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {from: fromCollectMessages(props.from)}
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          {this.state.from.map((from) => {
              return <div key={from._id} style={{cursor:'pointer'}}
                onClick={()=>alert(from.messages.join('\n'))}>
                  {from.fromUser}
              </div>;
          })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

render(<Name from={data}/>,el)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With the given constraints, I'd assume that messages are in order. Also, if they are not then consider adding a timestamp.

Moving forwards, this json can be shown as something like this:

```
John: hi
John: hey

Jane: ola
```

But what you're asking for is:

```
John: hi hey
Jane: ola
```

Following code will help merge similar users together:

```js
const chats = [
  {
    "message": "hi",
    "fromUser": "John",
    "fromUserId": "5edb1f10b82175355479f05a",
  },
  {
    "message": "hey",
    "fromUser": "John",
    "fromUserId": "5edb1f10b82175355479f05a",
  },
  {
    "message": "ola",
    "fromUser": "Jane",
    "fromUserId": "5ed9d49c7e516616600eb693",
  }
];

userChat = {};
// grouping the chat together
for (const msg of chats) {
  let user = msg.fromUserId;
  if (userChat[user] === undefined) {
    userChat[user] = msg;
  } else {
    userChat[user].message += " " + msg.message;
  }
}

// printing the msg out
for (const user in userChat) {
  console.log("User: ", userChat[user].fromUser);
  console.log("Message: ", userChat[user].message);
}
```

I've intentionally chosen this way so that it can be extended for multiple uses also. (just in case)

Answer (score 0):

you should use reducer, adapt this code to yours:

```
const arr = [
  { id: 1, name: "test1", msg: 'hi1' },
  { id: 2, name: "test2", msg: 'hi2' },
  { id: 2, name: "test3", msg: 'hi3' },
  { id: 3, name: "test4", msg: 'hi4' },
  { id: 4, name: "test5", msg: 'hi5' },
  { id: 5, name: "test6", msg: 'hi6' },
  { id: 5, name: "test7", msg: 'hi7' },
  { id: 6, name: "test8", msg: 'hi8' }
];

const filteredArr = arr.reduce((acc, current) => {
  const x = acc.find(item => item.id === current.id);
  if (!x) {
    return [...acc, current];
  } else {
    return acc.map(x=> x.id === current.id ? ({...x, msg: x.msg + current.msg }) : x)
  }
}, []);

console.log(filteredArr)
```

Result:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  msg: "hi1",
  name: "test1"
}, {
  id: 2,
  msg: "hi2hi3",
  name: "test2"
}, {
  id: 3,
  msg: "hi4",
  name: "test4"
}, {
  id: 4,
  msg: "hi5",
  name: "test5"
}, {
  id: 5,
  msg: "hi6hi7",
  name: "test6"
}, {
  id: 6,
  msg: "hi8",
  name: "test8"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have included all messages from an user inside an array `messages` inside the users object.

```
let users = [{
    "message": "hi",
    "fromUser": "John",
    "fromUserId": "5edb1f10b82175355479f05a",
  },
  {
    "message": "hey",
    "fromUser": "John",
    "fromUserId": "5edb1f10b82175355479f05a",
  },
  {
    "message": "ola",
    "fromUser": "Jane",
    "fromUserId": "5ed9d49c7e516616600eb693",
  },
  {
    "message": "hi",
    "fromUser": "John",
    "fromUserId": "5edb1f10b82175355479f05a",
  },
]

let flags = [],
  output = [];
users.forEach(user => {
  if (flags[user.fromUserId]) {
    output.forEach(item => {
      if (item.fromUserId === user.fromUserId) {
        item.messages = [...item.messages, user.message]
      }
    })
  } else {
    user.messages = [user.message]
    flags[user.fromUserId] = true;
    output.push(user);
  }
})
```

output will look like this:

```
output = [{
    "message": "hi",
    "fromUser": "John",
    "fromUserId": "5edb1f10b82175355479f05a",
    "messages": ["hi", "hey", "hi"]
  },
  {
    "message": "ola",
    "fromUser": "Jane",
    "fromUserId": "5ed9d49c7e516616600eb693",
    "messages": ["ola"]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
let output = input.reduce( (acc, cur) => {
    if(acc.map(item => item.fromUserId).includes(cur.fromUserId)){ //Check if the user is already included in the combined output
        let found  = acc.find(entry => entry.fromUserId === cur.fromUserId); //If found, combine the messages       
        found.message.push(cur.message);        
        return acc;
    } else {
        cur.message = [cur.message];    //the user is not included in the output yet   
        acc.push(cur);                  //so add it to the output
        return acc;
    }
}, []);
```

Full answer (Runnable code):

```js
let input = [
    {
        "message": "hi",
        "fromUser": "John",
        "fromUserId": "5edb1f10b82175355479f05a",
    },
    {
        "message": "hey",
        "fromUser": "John",
        "fromUserId": "5edb1f10b82175355479f05a",
    },
    {
        "message": "ola",
        "fromUser": "Jane",
        "fromUserId": "5ed9d49c7e516616600eb693",
    }
];


let output = input.reduce( (acc, cur) => {
    if(acc.map(item => item.fromUserId).includes(cur.fromUserId)){
        let found  = acc.find(entry => entry.fromUserId === cur.fromUserId);        
        found.message.push(cur.message);        
        return acc;
    } else {
        cur.message = [cur.message];
        acc.push(cur);
        return acc;
    }
}, []);
console.log(output);
```